# Fastest way to eliminate consecutive duplicates from array in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, algorithm, duplicates, array-algorithms

Prepping for interview.  Trying to work out a solution for the question "Fastest way to eliminate consecutive duplicates from array" using objective-C.  I.e input =[1,2,2,1,2,3,3,4] output =[1,2,1,2,3,4]

1. For in-array approach: Loop through element in array, if element == previous element, remove it and readjust all other elements to move step down.
2. For approach where we can use another array.  If element == previous element, don't add it to new "Unique array", else add it to Unique array.

Are there any better solutions?  Code is below.  Any optimizations possible?

**Using another array**

```
//Pseudocode for sucessive dup elimination when using another array 
    //
    //duplicateLessArray = empty array
    //previous element = not set
    //
    //for (loop through each element in origArray)
    //  if(previous element == not set or element != previous element)
    //    set previousElement = element 
    //    add element to duplicateLessArray
    //  

    NSMutableArray *duplicateLessArray ;

    duplicateLessArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;

    for (NSNumber *nextNumber in origArray)
    {
          if ([nextNumber intValue] != [[duplicateLessArray lastObject] intValue])
          {
            [duplicateLessArray addObject:nextNumber] ;
          }
     }

 NSLog(@"Duplicate less array = %@",duplicateLessArray) ;
```

**Using same array**

```
    //Pseudocode for in array sucessive dup elimination
    //
    //previous element = not set
    //
    //for (loop through each element in origArray)
    //  if(previous element == not set or element != previous element)
    //    set previousElement = element 
    //  else
    //      delete it from origArray
    //      move back all elements by 1

        NSInteger numElementsInDupLessArray = 0 ;
        NSNumber *prevElement ;
        for (NSNumber *nextNumber in [origArray copy])
        {
          if (numElementsInDupLessArray == 0 || [nextNumber intValue] != [prevElement intValue])
          {
            prevElement=nextNumber ;
            numElementsInDupLessArray++;
          }
          else
          {
            [origArray removeObjectAtIndex:numElementsInDupLessArray] ;
          } 
        }

   NSLog(@"Duplicate less array = %@",origArray) ;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing or algorithm design service.

Comment: This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I will use the other link moving forward.

Answer (score 3):

There is optimization for  in-array approach:

Instead of removing elements one-by-one (this may cause O(n^2) complexity) just shift single elements.
Pseudocode:

```
numOfRemoved = 0
GoodValue = A[0]
for i = 1 to arrayEnd //note start from 2nd element
  if A[i] = GoodValue then
    numOfRemoved++
  else
    GoodValue = A[i]
    A[i-numOfRemoved] = A[i]
Resize array once to (Length - numOfRemoved)
```

Example (' denotes current element, nr is numOfRemoved)

```
[5 5 1 7 7 7 4]   nr = 0  ; 5 stays at index 0
[5 '5 1 7 7 7 4]  nr = 0->1
[5 5 '1 7 7 7 4]  nr = 1 ; 1 goes to index 2-1 = 1
[5 1 1 '7 7 7 4]  nr = 1 ; 7 goes to index 2  
[5 1 7 7 '7 7 4]  nr = 1->2
[5 1 7 7 7 '7 4]  nr = 2->3
[5 1 7 4 7 7 '4]  nr = 3 ; 4 goes to index 6-3 = 3
[5 1 7 4]         resize
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I am too tired to work through it today!  Will check it tomorrow and accept if it works.